# Does a skeleton loader need to be accessible?

Tags: accessibility, loading

Are there concrete guidelines about accessibility in skeleton loaders? How might we design them to be more accessible?

Answer (score 4):

The guideline that comes to mind for me is WCAG 2.1 [Success Criterion 2.2.2, which states](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG/#pause-stop-hide):

> **Moving, blinking, scrolling**
>
> For any moving, blinking or scrolling information that (1) starts automatically, (2) lasts more than five
> seconds, and (3) is presented in parallel with other content, there is
> a mechanism for the user to pause, stop, or hide it unless the
> movement, blinking, or scrolling is part of an activity where it is
> essential;

When an entire screen is loading, the content is not "presented in parallel with other content", but some more asynchronous sites (like social media) do use skeletons at a content area level.

Additionally, screen readers might become tripped up by skeleton loading components and should use ARIA labels. [Ray Roman](https://medium.com/gronda/the-illusion-of-speed-loading-states-with-react-1c676ccce484) suggests:

> Season them with some combination of aria-disabled={true} and aria-label="loading"...

Comment: Thanks for the info!